# How to write a SQL query in Teradata that returns count of transactions by store per month?

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to write a query in Teradata that will return the count of the number of transactions that occurred in each store by month. The main problem I am finding is that transaction dates are stored as dates (obviously) and I want to group them by month-year. Below is my attempt at the query.

```
SELECT
COUNT(txn_nbr),
str_nbr,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM txn_dt) AS txn_month, EXTRACT (YEAR FROM txn_dt) AS txn_year

FROM tbl_name

WHERE str_nbr IN (xxxx, xxxx, xxxx)
AND fill_sold_dt BETWEEN '2016-12-31' AND '2017-08-31'
GROUP BY  4,3
```

The error message I'm getting is "SELECT Failed. 3504: Selected non-aggregate must be part of the associated group." Please, could anyone assist me in properly writing the query? I am not that experienced in SQL and I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You need to add `str_nbr` to your group by.  `GROUP BY 2,3,4`

Comment: JNevill, Thank you so much. This was exactly the problem. The query worked! Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Just FYI - You always need to group by all columns in your select statement that are not having the aggregate function performed on them.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. In retrospect, looking back at the error message I was receiving that makes perfect sense. I will remember this going forward. Thank you again. This made my day :)

Answer (score 2):

Need to group by str_nbr:

```
SELECT
COUNT(txn_nbr),
str_nbr,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM txn_dt) AS txn_month, 
EXTRACT (YEAR FROM txn_dt) AS txn_year

FROM tbl_name

WHERE str_nbr IN (xxxx, xxxx, xxxx)
AND fill_sold_dt BETWEEN '2016-12-31' AND '2017-08-31'
GROUP BY  2,3,4
```